# Installing bootloaders

Tags: operating-system, bootloader

I am creating a toy os and cannot find a good way to install the bootloader onto the first sector of a drive.

I use PARTCOPY but that only works on xp with floppy disks.

Does anyone know a program or method to install a 512 byte bin file onto the first sector of a drive.  Preferably the program can also read the first sector of a drive.

I am running windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dd in Linux can do that: 
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-copy-mbr/

For example (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dd_%28Unix%29#Master_boot_record_backup_and_restore), 
to backup the first sector of a harddrive:

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=MBR.img bs=512 count=1
```

to restore the first sector:

```
dd if=MBR.image of=/dev/sda
```

You can change /dev/sda to /dev/sda1 if you want to target the first partition instead of the entire disk.

Comment: Is there a dd for windows?

Comment: Technically, MSYS and GnuWin32 has windows ports of dd. But I haven't had success using them in windows. But you can easily turn a thumbdrive into a bootable linux (LiveUSB) these days, and they all contain the `dd` program.

Comment: Ubuntu has a program to create LiveUSB. According to this website: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows, you can also create a LiveUSB under windows.